# How to sum the output of multiple DATEDIF results in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

So, I’ve created an Excel sheet for work that sums the total between two dates (on multiple different lines) with each individual lines result being in the D, M , Y format.  No problem there.

[Here’s a screen shot of my Excel sheet thus far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNYMA.png)

The formula I’m using is =DATEDIF(A2,C2, “y”) &” years, “&DATEDIF(A2,C2, “ym”) &” months, “ &DATEDIF(A2,C2, “md”) &” days”

But now I need a formula to sum the results of all the lines into one aggregate total of them all.  Here’s the curveball - this sheet will be used as a calculator and the list of dates will change between each use.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to make three columns: one for =DATEDIF(A2,B2,"Y"), one for =DATEDIF(A2,B2,"YM"), and one for =DATEDIF(A2,B2,"MD"),

Then you can have a function in either a different column with Sum(C:C) or in the top row of that column with Sum(C2:C50) (this is assuming that you will have max 50 rows. you can set it to the bottom possible row if you want).

Here is how I did it (The sum function is a little different because I used google sheets):
[image]